# Use of USRP SDR to process sonar?

Tags: signal-analysis, software-implementation, sonar

I have ordered a USRP kit to do radio signal processing in software. Is there a way to use the same device to process sonar data? What would I do upconvert the sonar to 50 MHz?

Comment: What is the frequency and bandwidth of the sonar data?

Comment: @Jim Clay Sonar data is 30 Hz to 20 KHz and there may be perhaps 100 or 1000 samples per second.

Comment: I don't understand- is the data digitized already?  If it isn't, what do you mean by "100 or 1000 samples per second"?  If it is, how do you cover 20 kHz with 1000 samples/s?  And why do you want to convert it to analog so that you can put it into a USRP?  You could just process the digitized data directly.

Comment: What do you need a USRP for if you want to do sonar in the range of 0-30 kHz?! Just use a soundcard instead of a USRP. The GnuRadio software is able to use soundcards as sources and sinks as well.

Comment: Thats a good point.